# How to save a table row data in the session when button is clicked in a datatable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatable

I have a datatable called "Add Products". Using this table I want to save table row data in a session variable called "Ordered Products" by clicking "Add" button in the table. Every row has a button.

```
<tbody>
                            <?php foreach ($productsWithDiscounts as $product): ?>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><?=  h($product['product_code'])?></td>
                                    <td><?=  h($product['description'])?></td>
                                    <td><?=  h($product['product_group_name'])?></td>
                                    <td><?=  h($product['available_qty'])?></td>
                                    <td><?=  h($product['price'])?></td>
                                    <td>10</td>
                                    <td>10</td>
                                    <td>10</td>
                                    <td>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="number" class="form-control cus-nopadding" name="items[0][distributor_margin]">
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                    <td class="Add">
                                        <a class="btn btn-primary">Add</a>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            <?php endforeach; ?>
</tbody>
```

Above is the tbody of the table.

I tried below code in the script to check when the button is clicked is it opening a alert box. But that is also not working.

```
$('#productList tbody').on( 'click', 'button', function () {
        // var data = table.row( $(this).parents('tr') ).data();
        alert( "Product is added!" );
    } );
```

Can someone help me on this issue?

what I want to do is to save table row data in a session variable when the "Add" button is clicked.

Comment: Is hard to see exactly what this the problem. Can you copy/past all your code.

Comment: I am asking a way to save the table row data in a session variable when clicking the "Add" button in the datatable. Can you think of a way to do that according to the above code?